# Transform label attribute in handlebars from Ember component

Tags: ember.js

I am attempting to fix an issue caused by the 1.13 upgrade with my internationalization/localization implementation.  Nine times out of ten, the default label attribute will appear, but occasionally, we will need to serve up an alternate label based on the user's language settings.

The handlebars template, as it is now, has the following:

```
{{button-widget label="sample" action="actionHandler"}}
```

Pre 1.13, we would add a function in the component, called on init, that will look up the current langauge setting, and set "this.label" to whatever the result is within our locale file.

```
i18n: function() {
    ...
}.on('init')
```

The {...} looks up the appropriate locale file for the key "test", and updates the label attribute with the result if one is found.  For instance, if the user were french, a lookup of "test" might return "échantillon".

From some research, as of 1.13, Ember no longer allows updates to attributes on init.  They did, however, create a few new hooks to help (including didInitAttrs and didReceiveAttrs). Unfortunately though, none of them seem to allow me to override the label attribute.

I am attempting to do this without relying on an ugly jQuery hack, and since this is a project being consumed by other applications, button labels may not always be available within the button, so just adding the label to a model and referencing a variable likely isn't a reliable solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Comment: You could use `didInsertElement` to do all of that.

Answer (score 0):

As Kitler mentioned you could use didInsertElement for all that.

```
App.GenericComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        // Your magic here
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if you need to get access to the store, you can use it as a service by defining a property containing the service:

```
App.GenericComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),
    didInsertElement: function() {
        // Your magic here

        // Like so
        this.get("store").find("model");
    }
}
```

If your language settings are not located in a data store, you could simply attach the object containing the information to the component like you're used to.